# Librería para reportear HTML

Tags: html5, angularjs

Señores, quien conoce alguna libreria para convertir html con una gran cantidad de información en pdf, paginado. Utilice kendo pero no me lo permite paginar y se totea al momento de generar el pdf. He buscado muchas librerias pero sin ningun resultado. Estoy utilizando angular JS. y el html 5.

Comment: yo utilizo el siguiente con Node, Meteor pero puede ser utilizado con cualquier framework de js https://github.com/NilsDannemann/meteor-pdfmake/

Comment: Amigo me podrias dar un ejemplo.

Comment: ya escribe una manera muy simple, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar la libreria de pdfMake, la cual puedes obtenerla desde [pdfMake](https://github.com/sajeetharan/angularPDFgenerator) o descargarla desde el NPM [pdfMake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake).

Un ejemplo simple es declarar tu objeto

```
var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };
```

cuyo contenido sera mostrado en el pdf, y sera implementado:

```
$scope.downloadPdf = function() {
 pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
};
```